# How should I group wrapped UIKit components to improve accessibility support?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, xcode-ui-testing, uiaccessibility

I have difficulties understanding what is the right way to make a custom UIView accessible on iOS. As a case study, here is a custom  `UIControl` subclass wrapping a `UILabel` and a `UITextField` subviews, that I want to test via a UI test.

View hierarchy:

```
→ UIControl
  ↪︎ UILabel
  ↪︎ UIView
```

Intended behavior:

[image: Snapshot of expected behavior]

---

### 1️⃣ The default behavior

By default, the behavior is not great:

- The accessibility inspector inspects the two subviews as unrelated;
- The accessibility inspector’s audit raises a “hit area is too small” warning since it is ignoring the whole `UIControl` can be tapped and will give focus to the `UITextField`.

But this testing code works fine:

```swift
let emailField = app.textFields["Email"]
emailField.tap()
emailField.typeText("toto@tata.com")
```

### 2️⃣ Becoming an accessibility element

If the `UIControl` becomes flagged as an accessibility element as following, the accessibility inspector will show only 1 pointer for the whole `UIControl` but the UI test will fail.

Here is the code:

```swift
isAccessibilityElement = true
accessibilityLabel = innerLabel.text
accessibilityValue = innerTextField.text
accessibilityTraits = innerTextField.accessibilityTraits
```

And the test failure stack, that seems to have an *Element subtree* limited to the `UIControl` (aka `TextField`) itself

```
UI Test Activity: 
Assertion Failure: SampleUITests.swift:21: Failed to synthesize event: Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus. Event dispatch snapshot: TextField, label: 'Email'
Element debug description:
Attributes: TextField, {{32.0, 229.0}, {350.0, 52.0}}, label: 'Email'
Element subtree:
 →TextField, 0x600000925340, {{32.0, 229.0}, {350.0, 52.0}}, label: 'Email'
```

### 3️⃣ Simplifying accessibility information

Inspired by [Apple’s documentation on how to **simplify your accessibility information**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/supporting_voiceover_in_your_app#3023624) , I used the following code:

```swift
var elements = [UIAccessibilityElement]()
let groupedElements = UIAccessibilityElement(accessibilityContainer: self)
groupedElements.accessibilityLabel = innerLabel.text
groupedElements.accessibilityTraits = innerTextField.accessibilityTraits
elements.append(groupedElements)
```

Which seems to do nothing: I’m back to the default behavior.

### Wrapping things up

I’d like to have the accessibility structure from 2️⃣ and still be able to run UI tests in the most expressive way ie using the same code as 1️⃣, how can I do this?
What did I do wrong in 3️⃣ that made it behave the same way as 1️⃣?

---

### Edits

1. As hinted by @Defragged, I tried to improve the `UIControl`s compliance to `UIResponder` but it didn't really help:

   ```swift
   override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
       return innerTextField.canBecomeFirstResponder
   }

   override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
       return innerTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
   }

   override var isFirstResponder: Bool {
       return innerTextField.isFirstResponder
   }
   ```
2. Scrutinizing the UI test error logs a little deeper, I read this:

   ```
   t =     9.65s         Synthesize event
   t =     9.68s             Get number of matches for: Elements containing elements matching predicate 'hasKeyboardFocus == 1'
   t =     9.72s                 Requesting snapshot of accessibility hierarchy for app with pid 24879
   t =     9.74s                 Find: Descendants matching type TextField
   t =     9.74s                 Find: Elements matching predicate '"Email" IN identifiers'
   t =     9.74s                 Find: Elements containing elements matching predicate 'hasKeyboardFocus == 1'
   ```

   It seems that `XCUIElement` instances have a undocumented `hasKeyboardFocus` attribute that can be inspected with a debugger but that I have no clue how to control ‍♂️.

Comment: I think you're on the right track with "2", but without seeing your custom `UIControl` implementation, it's hard to see exactly what's going wrong. Is your custom `UIControl` doing its responder chain stuff correctly (as in, does it implement `canBecomeFirstResponder`, `isFirstResponder` etc? I imagine your implementations would just want to forward to the inner text field. I suspect your test is tapping inside of the main control, but outside of the inner field, so it doesn't get focus, so then the test's keyboard input then doesn't work.

Comment: Is the keyboard up on screen when the test fails in 2?

Comment: @Defragged I actually don't, I have a simple target handler for `.touchUpInside` events that basically calls `innerTextField.becomeFirstResponder()`, which is enough to put the keyboard up on screen (cc @Oletha)

Comment: I added an edit section to the question to give updates on new attempts. No luck though.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Given the error you've posted, which of your controls has the `accessibilityIdentifier` of `Email`? Is it the inner `UITextField`, or the outer `UIControl`?

Comment: @Defragged it is the inner `UITextField`. I tried giving this identifier to the `UIControl`: no behavior change.

Comment: I was thinking this morning about another approach that might work: If you make the outer component not accessible at all, but have only the inner component be accessible, when you set the label on the outer control, you can update the accessibility label on the inner field to have the new value ("email" or whatever). Also, whenever the frame of the outer control changes, update the accessibility frame of the inner field with the frame out of the outer control. Now as far as accessibility knows, there's only one control,  but with the combined attributes of both that you're interested in.

Comment: I've put up together a tiny project to show up my issues here: https://github.com/dirtyhenry/aristide.

Comment: @Defragged not sure how easy it is to play with the accessibility frame with a auto layout lifecycle but will report results here when I do.

Comment: It should be safe. Autolayout is essentially just computing frames from your constraints anyway, and the accessibility frameworks don't give you any other mechanism. Since you're just taking one object's `accessibilityFrame` and applying it to something else, you shouldn't need to compute anything yourself. Just make sure you're updating it at the correct times. If you are computing the frame yourself, just be aware that `accessibilityFrame` is in screen coordinates.